# Bluemix: IBM Push Notification issues

Tags: push-notification, ibm-cloud, ibm-mobile-services

I was using an instance of the Push service in my app, but now I want to move my app to a different organization.

I found this link that saying that the Push service is discontinued: https://developer.ibm.com/bluemix/2015/12/15/important-mobile-services-announcement/, so I have migrated from the Push service to the IBM Push Notification service. After making the change I have the following problem.

1. I am not able to see my registered devices in the monitoring area of Bluemix yet I can fetch the list of registered devices using a REST API. Why is that happening? [Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/j3AuR.png)
2. I am not able to find a REST API to send a notification to a **particular deviceID** like I was doing before with the Push service. How can I do that with the new service? Alternatively, is there a way to create an instance of the original Push service in my new organization?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. The registered devices list was removed in the move to the new push service as you note, I'll reach out to the push team to see about the possibility of reintroducing it and add a comment with their reply. Right now you are correct in that the only way to grab the list of devices and their deviceIds is through the REST API.
2. You should be able to use POST /apps/{applicationId}/messages, specifying any number of deviceIDs in the 'target' array . You can see the full json model for the call by clicking the "Model" tag under the "Response Class" header rather than "Model Schema" as shown:
   [image]